# If $f_{n} = a_{n}b_{n} + c_{n}$ where $a_{n} \to \infty$, $|b_{n}| \geq C_{1}$ and $|c_{n}|\leq 1$. Then $|f_{n}| \geq C > 0$.

Tags: sequences-and-series

If $f_{n} = a_{n}b_{n} + c_{n}$ where $a_{n} \to \infty$, $|b_{n}| \geq C_{1}$ and $|c_{n}|\leq 1$. Then $|f_{n}| \geq  C > 0$. Here, $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Note that
$$
|f_{n}| = |a_{n}b_{n} + c_{n}| \geq |a_{n}b_{n}| - |c_{n}| \geq C_{1}|a_{n}| - 1
$$
Since $a_{n} \to \infty$, then given $M > 0$, there is $N_{0} \in \mathbb{N}$ such that
$$
|a_{n}| > M, \ \ n\geq N_{0}
$$
Then
$$
|f_{n}| \geq C_{1}|a_{n}| - 1 > MC_{1} - 1, \ \ \text{for all} \ n \geq N_{0}
$$

Now, let $f_{n}^{1} = f_{n}$ for $n \geq N_{0}$ and $f_{n}^{2} = f_{n}$ for $n < N_{0}$.
Let $ 0 < \alpha= \text{max}\left(|f_{1}|, ... , |f_{N_{0}}|\right)$. Therore, $|f_{n}| = |f_{n}^{2}| \leq \alpha$ for all $n < N_{0}$.

So I just take $M = \frac{1+2\alpha}{C_{1}} $.  Then
$$
|f_{n}| = |f_{n}^{1} + f_{n}^{2}| \geq |f_{n}^{1}| - |f_{n}^{2}| > 2\alpha  - \alpha = \alpha > 0
$$

Comment: If you really want your constant to be positive you have to take $M$ slightly bigger than $\frac{1}{C_1}$ e.g. $M=\frac{1}{C_1}+1$ would do the job.

Comment: @user99432 Right. Thanks

Comment: You need to consider also the $$\min_{n\le N_0}\left\{|f_n|\right\}$$

Comment: I think you have to clarify what you really want to show. If you want to know that $|f_n|\geq C>0$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$ you have to include all the $n's$ before $N_0$ because as you remarked there exists $N$ such that this estimate is true for all $n$ follwing $N_0$. But for all $n=1,...,N_0-1$ this might not be true.

Comment: @user99432 I edited the answer, could you tell me if everything is ok?

Comment: @MarianaCoub if you define $f_n^1$ and $f_n^2$ like this then $f_n=f_n^1+f_n^2$ only if you additionally say that $f_n^1=0$ for all $n<N_0$ and $f_n^2=0$ for all $n\geq N_0$. Anyways you can not really tell that $\max\{|f_1|,...,|f_{N_0-1}|\}>0$ at least I don't see why. Is there any information you didn't share with us or is it possible that you only what to find some index $N_0$ so that $|f_n|\geq C>0$ for all $n\geq N_0$. Just to convince you that this is not necessarily true, take $a_n=0$ for all $n<N_0$ and $c_n=0$ for all $n<N_0$ then $\max\{|f_1|,...,|f_{N_0-1}|\}=0$.